# Select in a first form / menu, the choices of other fields in other forms

Tags: 8, forms

I have three types of content, which represents categories.

In each type of content, I have a first field which offers to select a subcategory (different subcategories depending on the type of content).

To simplify the creation of a node for my users, I would like them to be able to select in a first form field directly the subcategory (therefore among all the subcategories of the different types of content).

For example:

Three types of content: A, B and C.

A has as subcategories: A1, A2, A3; B has as subcategories: B1, B2, B3; and C has as subcategories: C1, C2, C3.

When the user creates a node, the first field of the form offers to choose from all the sub-categories, namely: A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3.

Do you know how to do it ?

I thought about creating a first page with a menu with all the subcategories allowing to redirect to the corresponding form with the first pre-filled field, but in this case it would be necessary that the links contain the information of the first field

Comment: This question is very unclear.  You wrote "Three types of content: A, B, and C"-- Are those Drupal **content types**?  Then you wrote, "When the user creates a node, the first field of the form offers to choose from all the sub-categories, namely: A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3."  If each content type has its own set of subcategories, why would you want users to be able to select from all the subcategories, including ones not for the current content type?

Comment: Yes, "Drupal content types". There is not "current content type". When you create a node, first, you have the choice on what type of content you want to create (article, page etc.), and after that you have the content type form. The goal is to skip the step of choosing the type of content, and to allow the user to choose immediately among all the sub-categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want a list of 9 links, and clicking a link sends the users to the **node add** form for the relevant content type with the **Subcategory** field already filled in.

As you noted in your question, you can use a menu for this.  The challenge is how to pre-fill the first field.

For that, you can use the [Prepopulate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate).

As noted on the project page, this allows you to make a link like this to automatically set the value of fields.  For example, to set the title:

```
http://www.example.com/node/add/page?edit[title][widget][0][value]=My awesome page
```

Also note the security warning on the page:

> For security reasons, Drupal 8 version of this module does not support
> radios/checkboxes.

Since subcategories are probably a taxonomy entity reference or text list, I assume this module will be fine for your case.